# hybris backoffice: In advanced-search show a field to a certain user group

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, advanced-search, backoffice

Is it possible to not show a field in backoffice advanced-search view depending on user group of the current user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution finally. Just use the property attribute

> principal

in the tag  for your advanced-search and specify which group should use which tag. So, you can specify multiple advanced-search context tag for multiple principals.